# Symfony 2 - Guzzle 6.X HTTP | get the body response

Tags: php, symfony, http, guzzle6

I am using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses) with Symfony 2.7.3 and I don't know why I have the header of the response but not the body. (I am on localhost with WAMP)

```
$donnees = array(// Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => $urlAuth,
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'timeout'  => 2.0,
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
                'Accept'     => 'application/json'
            ],
            'verify' => false,
            'json'      => ["Id" => $Id, 
                                                "Username" => $username,
                                                "Password" => $password,
                                                "SecretId" => $secretId]
            );

        $client = new Client($donnees);

        $response = $client->post( '/auth/', $donnees );
dump($response);
```

so I got :

[image]

But stream is empty whereas I should get a token (you can see content-length : 69)

Can you help me, I don't know that I missed...

(The server only accept POST to get the token)

Comment: $body = $response->getBody();

Comment: I know, but it's just give the object Stream and it's empty (the same as the screen)

Comment: Are you sure? I tested now, when I dump $response I get exactly what you get, but if I dump `..->getBody()` then I have the body.

Comment: Yep, you can check http://vgy.me/wyqBMI.png it's the same than my screen  :/   It's very strange !

Comment: Nothing strange, try `json_decode($response->getBody(), true)`

Comment: sorry, but `$response->json()` don't work?

Comment: Nop because with the V6, it's PSR-7 ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's json response you should decode it, add:

```
$response_body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

`true` means that returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: I don't understand why the stream look empty but with decode I have the content. Thank you very much!

Comment: Because guzzle response body is a PHP stream, you must perform operation on it to get what you want (I'm not PHP master so maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

By calling `$response->getBody()` you obtain a *GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream* object.
This class has a useful *__toString()* method, so the following line will work as expected :

`$response_body = (string)$response->getBody();`